How to Implement multiple Custom Components in react-select
I'm using react-select package.
I want to customize the chip in react-select  isMulti={true}
The issue that I'm having is I'm able to pass only one Custom Component into component props api in react-select.
import React from "react";
import EmojiIcon from "@atlaskit/icon/glyph/emoji";
import Tooltip from "@atlaskit/tooltip";
import Select, { components, MultiValueRemoveProps } from "react-select";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const MultiValueRemove = (props: MultiValueRemoveProps<ColourOption>) => {
  return (
    <components.MultiValueRemove {...props}>
      <EmojiIcon label="Emoji" primaryColor={colourOptions[2].color} />
    </components.MultiValueRemove>
  );
};

const MultiValue = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
        borderRadius: "20px",
        padding: "5px 10px",
        marginRight: "5px",
        cursor: "pointer",
      }}
    >
      <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{props?.data?.label}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{
      MultiValue,

      MultiValueRemove,
    }}
    styles={{
      multiValueRemove: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        border: `1px dotted ${colourOptions[2].color}`,
        height: "100%",
      }),
    }}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
  />
);


But this works to remove the drop down icon am I missing anything specific
     components={{
          MultiValue: (props) => <ValueComponent data={props.data}/>,
          DropdownIndicator: () => null,
          IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
        }}


here is the improved code..
make sure you are not nesting the MultiValueRemove component inside the MultiValue component improperly
import React from "react";
import Select, { components, MultiValueRemoveProps, MultiValueProps } from "react-select";
import EmojiIcon from "@atlaskit/icon/glyph/emoji";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const MultiValueRemove = (props: MultiValueRemoveProps<ColourOption>) => {
  return (
    <components.MultiValueRemove {...props}>
      <EmojiIcon label="Emoji" primaryColor={colourOptions[2].color} />
    </components.MultiValueRemove>
  );
};

const MultiValue = (props: MultiValueProps<ColourOption>) => {
  return (
    <components.MultiValueContainer {...props}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
          borderRadius: "20px",
          padding: "5px 10px",
          marginRight: "5px",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
      >
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{props.data.label}</p>
        <components.MultiValueRemove {...props} />
      </div>
    </components.MultiValueContainer>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{
      MultiValue,
      MultiValueRemove,
      DropdownIndicator: () => null,
      IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
    }}
    styles={{
      multiValueRemove: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        border: `1px dotted ${colourOptions[2].color}`,
        height: "100%",
      }),
    }}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
  />
);


Just tried the above code it seems to  not work.Here is the implementation in a codesandbox:
The label seems to repeat and the remove icon is not showing
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/codesandboxer-example-forked-6pm3sj?file=%2Findex.html
